# htaccess trailing slash issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, trailing-slash

I am getting some problem for without trailing slash url. I searched in Google, but not able to get the exact result.

```
  From Url : local.xxxx.com/stories
```

When I am trying with the above Url, It redirects to

```
  To Url : local.xxxx.com/sapp/View//stories/
```

Htaccess:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/View/%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/View/%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ /app/View/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Now I am getting 403 Forbidden error. You don't have permission to access /app/View//storieson this server.

If I will add trailing slash, then its working perfectly. If there is no slash, we can add slash at the end of the url if there are no params.

Can any body suggest how can I achieve this.

Comment: Where do you add the trailing slash?

Comment: Never mind... @anubhava to the rescue. ;)

Comment: If we add slash at the end of the Url, It will work fine. If there is no slash at the end of the url, it redirects to views folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely due to the fact that `/app/View/stories/` is a real directory and Apache's `mod_dir` is adding a trailing slash.

You can fix using this code:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

# internally add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/View/%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ /app/View/%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L] 

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/View/%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/View/%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ /app/View/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: @Anuhava, Still url redirects to /app/View/stories/. Your assumption is perfect. but its not working for me.

Comment: Question has been updated. We can Add slash at the end of the url if there are no params and .php extentions. Please check once

Comment: What happens when you enter `http://domaon.com/app/View/stories` in browser? Does that also give 403? Try adding `Options +Indexes` at top of your .htaccess

Comment: @anubava. I fixed this by using the below code.                         RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/View/%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ /app/View/%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]

Comment: Ah that's right, glad it worked (answer updated with your working rule)

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. Its working fine as per Url prospective. Getting another problem... In my all view pages, I am using Href links "./list.php" . Previously its working as expected. Now, It is taking from root path. Not taking from DocumentRoot/stories/list.php. So, I need to Append trailing Slash physically. any suggesstions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96322/discussion-between-robert-and-anubhava).

Comment: Sorry I just came online. Is `list.php` located physically in `/app/View/` directory?